# 「君の声が聞こえなくて、逢えると信じる。」

Tags: grammar

For a research project in artificial intelligence, I investigated parsing Japanese. There was major problems with ambiguity in the mentioned type of sentence; in most cases the ambiguity is obvious to resolve, but I kinda need the opinion of a native speaker in this case.

My theory is that the 、 is enough to disambiguate between:

> 「君の声が聞こえなくて逢えると信じる。」
>
> I believe that I would be able to [meet you without hearing your voice]. (Perhaps meet while bound and gagged in a prison?)

and

> 「君の声が聞こえなくて、逢えると信じる。」
>
> Even without hearing your voice, I believe that I am able to meet you. (not hearing goes with believe, not meet)

Or maybe both sentences are wrong...they feel awkward to me :/

Am I correct in assuming the comma is crucial there?

Comment: What if there's context where like, two people are on the phone and someone's silence implies that they will be able to meet, so it becomes "*because* I can't hear your voice, I believe we will meet"?

Comment: With or without a comma, that sentence makes no sense if you want an honest comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two examples sound kind of weird, so let me add a particle も to make them sound natural and understandable.

> A. 君の声が聞こえなくても逢えると信じる。
>   B. 君の声が聞こえなくても、逢えると信じる。

Now the two meanings:

> 1. (I believe) **I can meet you without hearing your voice**.
> 2. **I believe without hearing your voice** (that I can meet you).

I think in most cases B means 2. But I can't say for sure that B never means 1. Punctuation is sometimes arbitrary.

As for A, it seems completely ambiguous to me. In fact, I find this sentence somewhat hard to understand.

In order to make it mean 1, inserting a comma like 君の声が聞こえなくても逢える、と信じる may also be possible.

Comment: Would using brackets like "I believe [I can meet you without hearing your voice]" help with what you were trying to show in meanings 1 and 2?